# Can I create an Apache Spark Word2VecModel with pretrained embeddings?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, word2vec, apache-spark-ml, word-embedding

I want to use word embeddings in my Python Spark text classification pipeline. The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#word2vec) shows how to train your own embeddings, but I would like to use a pretrained set like GloVe. Is there some way to initialize a Word2VecModel with pretrained embeddings or do I have to write my own transformer class?